# validating numeric values in text box

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers

I have to allow user to allow only numeric values in the text box . It should remove any non numeric method. No matter how they are supplying the input ...either typing or copy+paste.

My code

```
var nCheck  = function (field) {
var re = /^[0-9]*$/;
               if (!re.test(field.value)) {

                       field.value = field.value.replace(/[^0-9]*$/g,"");
               }
 };
```

This works except when you copy paste something like aaa2 . Whereas aaaa or aa work. Problem is when last place contains number it fails .

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what event is using your function as callback? `keydown`, `keyup` or `change`?

Comment: keyup event . $(selector).keyup(function(){ ncheck(this)})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` means "end of string". Remove it and it should work.

Other tips:

Replace `*` by `+`; `*` includes the empty string

Maybe it should better to warn the user, just in case the numeric character is a typo (like pressing Q instead of 1)

Answer (score 4):

Just do

```
field.value = field.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
```

This will replace everything that's not a number for nothing, and you don't even have to run the `test` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, check out [textola](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) a jquery numeric plugin.

Answer (score 0):

No regex:

```
field.value = isNaN(field.value) ? '' : field.value;
```